# Excel error : "Not enough memory"

Tags: ms-office, memory

A friend of mine just bought an MBA. He installed Office 2011 in order to work mainly with Excel. As he opened one of his file (6.5MB - multiple sheets - company logo - no graphs) and wanted to save it this box appears: [image: Excel error picture]

where you can read something like `Not enough memory`. If I click on <kbd>OK</kbd> the box appears again like 15 times.

Thinking of an installation issue, I tried on my MBP which did the same result. But his old computer (win7 - Excel 2013) can open and save the file without any issue.

During my google searches, the only result that I found led me to a Windows based solution or an help site from 1994...

Comment: Is it running on the latest version of office 2010?

Comment: @JashJacob I guess, how can I figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file was saved as `Excel 95` and was to big for the destination file. A simple `save As` with the new format `xlsx` solve the issue.

Comment: @Buscar웃 trust me, for a so stupid solution, I also regret the time I spent on this.

Comment: as long you have the solution it is all OK :)

Comment: I will try this on my problematic file!